# How to see if object is behind a wall and if it's in field of view?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made this code to see if it's in FOV and it works but if I'm far and if I'm on his side the number returned is greater than 0 and that means I'm front of him when I am not.

```
Vector3 objectNormalized = Vector3.Normalize(transform.position);
Vector3 targetNormalized = Vector3.Normalize(target.position);
Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(transform.forward);
Vector3 pos = targetNormalized - objectNormalized;
```

Also, how can I see if it's behind a wall or another object? I'm coding an AI so I really need this.

Answer (score 2):

For detecting if no collider is between you and the object do a [physics raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) from your camera to the objects center and check if `RaycastHit.collider.gameObject` is the object you raycasted to. Depending on your use case you might want to try a few raycasts to different parts of the model.

As for being in the field of view, you have procedural [`TestPlanesAABB`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html) or event-based [`OnBecameVisible`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html) and [`OnBecameInvisible`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html). If you decide on using [`TestPlanesAABB`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html), remember to update the plane array on camera movement, not just start as in the example.